# Copy a row to multiple rows based on value

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, stock, ohlc

I cannot figure out a problem on stocks data. We have a `dataframe` with high, low and dates data. I want to make two new columns with max from `24_H` and min from `24_L` of whole week (min and max of whole week from days of week and copy it to every day/row of that week) problem is some days are missing (holidays) so you can not use a loop for every 5 rows. Hope that make sense I tried to explain it in a picture in excel and manually did it on two weeks (38 and 39).

EDIT:
part of the code. how to print high and low value of each week :
df.groupby(['YEAR', 'WEEK']).agg({'24_H': 'max', '24_L': 'min'})
but still don´t know how to print them back for every day of the week

EDIT2 part of the data (DoW is day of week):

| DATE | DoW | 24_H | 24_L | WEEK | MONTH | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12.09.2005 | 1 | 1170.0 | 1165.0 | 37 | 9 | 2005 |
| 13.09.2005 | 2 | 1166.0 | 1157.0 | 37 | 9 | 2005 |
| 14.09.2005 | 3 | 1162.0 | 1151.0 | 37 | 9 | 2005 |
| 15.09.2005 | 4 | 1158.0 | 1150.0 | 37 | 9 | 2005 |
| 16.09.2005 | 5 | 1164.0 | 1152.0 | 37 | 9 | 2005 |
| 19.09.2005 | 1 | 1162.0 | 1153.0 | 38 | 9 | 2005 |
| 20.09.2005 | 2 | 1162.0 | 1145.0 | 38 | 9 | 2005 |
| 21.09.2005 | 3 | 1149.0 | 1134.0 | 38 | 9 | 2005 |
| 22.09.2005 | 4 | 1142.0 | 1130.0 | 38 | 9 | 2005 |
| 23.09.2005 | 5 | 1144.0 | 1134.0 | 38 | 9 | 2005 |
| 26.09.2005 | 1 | 1148.0 | 1136.0 | 39 | 9 | 2005 |
| 27.09.2005 | 2 | 1145.0 | 1135.0 | 39 | 9 | 2005 |
| 28.09.2005 | 3 | 1146.0 | 1137.0 | 39 | 9 | 2005 |
| 29.09.2005 | 4 | 1154.0 | 1136.0 | 39 | 9 | 2005 |
| 30.09.2005 | 5 | 1155.0 | 1149.0 | 39 | 9 | 2005 |

Data in excel:

[image: Image of data in excel]

Comment: Please paste in the data, not an image. Thanks.

Comment: You can do a lot of things with missing values for a given week. You can ignore them, replace them as the mean of the values of that week, the median, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the groupby() as you've described, then do an inner join ([pandas.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)) to copy the new (grouped) DF's data back to the main one. Also use reset_index() to make the YEAR and WEEK columns instead of an index in weekly_limits:

```
weekly_limits = df.groupby(['YEAR', 'WEEK']).agg(
    {'24_H': 'max', '24_L': 'min'}
).reset_index()
df_with_weekly_limits = pandas.merge(df, weekly_limits, on=['YEAR', 'WEEK'])
```

Comment: Sarah you are the best thank you! Have a great one and all the best for New Year!